# How to create Python Stub Files and where to put?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint, python-extensions, pyi

I have a compiled a Python extension.
The resulting binary `mylib.so` file can be imported in the Python script and works fine.

Now I am wondering how to write the interface stub file `mylib.pyi` such, that pylint and the Python language server used in VS Code can use it?

For now the native library is just in the root of my scripts.
When putting the `mylib.pyi` next to it pylint ignores it.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is a year old but the answer might help the next person. I managed to do this by writing the following setup file:

```py
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
extension = Extension(
    name = 'dummy',
    sources = ...,
    ...
)
    
setup(
    name = 'dummy',
    ext_modules = [extension],
    packages = ['dummy'],
    package_dir = {'dummy' : './stub'},
    package_data = {
        'dummy': ['__init__.pyi', 'py.typed']
    }
)
```

From what I understand, the `stub` directory is treated as a separate package and installed alongside the extension. I've only tested it with vscode but I believe all IDEs should be able to parse it. Full code can be found [here](https://github.com/hos-b/dummy-c-extension).